# Update followed by insert in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm not sure that's the correct way making an update followed by insert in a stored procedure.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[io_sp_admin_add_emp]
    @id BIGINT,
    @lastName VARCHAR(20), 
    @firstName VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [TranAddEmp]
       DECLARE @identity BIGINT = 0 

       INSERT INTO empTable(LastName, FirstName, hash_id)
       VALUES (@lastName, @firstName,
               HashBytes('SHA2_256', CAST(@id AS VARBINARY(50))))

       SELECT @identity = @@identity

       UPDATE empTable
       SET rowId = incId  -- both are columns in empTable
       WHERE hash_id = @identity

       COMMIT TRANSACTION [TranAddEmp]   
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [TranAddEmp]
    END CATCH                  
END
```

Comment: Where does the `incId` column value is coming from? Are you updating the same row you've just added or a different row related to it?

Comment: Why would you expect hash_id to be equal to the auto generated id of your row? I assume `id` in your table is the primary key and is an auto increment integer field? If not you'll have to explain the schema. Also it's unclear why you can't set that value in the insert statement? Are you trying to update a different row maybe? The code doesn't make clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Also, the result of `HashBytes('SHA2_256', cast(@id as varbinary(50)))` is a varbinary, it can't be equal to the bigint stored by your identity column. Another thing - `@@identity` will return the last identity value generated on the database. You should use `scope_identity()` instead (or the `output` clause in the `insert` statement.

Comment: Basically, I'm sending an `id` from client to the `sp`, but I can't keep the value as it is so I would like to use `HASH`. I'll change the `id` to `varbinary` as well if that's what you mean. `incId` is just another column in the table. wll `@@identity` keep the `HASH` created in `HasBytes` statement?

Comment: No. I've already explained what `@@identity` does.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple change to your current code can give you what you're looking for.
Instead of messing around with `@@Identity`, which is almost never the right thing to do, you compute the hash of the `@Id` value once, store it in a local variable, and use it for both the `insert` statement and the `where` clause of the `update` statement - That is, assuming the `HashId` column is unique.

That being said, I'm not sure why you need the `rowId` column as well as the `incId` column - unless one of them is designed to change it's value through an update statement in the lifetime of the row - you are simply keeping redundant data.

Here's an improved version of your stored procedure:

```
CRETAE PROCEDURE [dbo].[io_sp_admin_add_emp]
    @id BIGINT,
    @lastName varchar(20), 
    @firstName varchar(20)      
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION [TranAddEmp]

        -- Compute the hash once, store in a local variable
        DECLARE @HashId varbinary(8000) = HashBytes('SHA2_256', cast(@id as varbinary(50)))

        INSERT INTO empTable(
            LastName,
            FirstName,
            hash_id
        )
        VALUES(
            @lastName,
            @firstName,
            @HashId
        )

         UPDATE empTable
         SET rowId = incId  
         WHERE hash_id = @HashId

        COMMIT TRANSACTION [TranAddEmp]   
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        -- make sure transaction has started and is not commited
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [TranAddEmp]
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a great keyword `OUTPUT`. [As MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns information from, or expressions based on, each row affected
>   by an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement. These results can be
>   returned to the processing application for use in such things as
>   confirmation messages, archiving, and other such application
>   requirements. The results can also be inserted into a table or table
>   variable. Additionally, you can capture the results of an OUTPUT
>   clause in a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement, and
>   insert those results into a target table or view.

You can insert your inserted id's into table through `OUTPUT` keyword. For example:

```
DECLARE @InsertedIDs TABLE (ID varbinary(8000))

INSERT INTO empTable(
    LastName,
    FirstName,
    hash_id
 )
OUTPUT HashBytes('SHA2_256', cast(INSERTED.ID as varbinary(50))) INTO @InsertedIDs(ID)
 VALUES(
 @lastName,
 @firstName,
 HashBytes('SHA2_256', cast(@id as varbinary(50)))
 )

UPDATE empTable
Set rowId = incId  -- both are columns in empTable
WHERE hash_id in (SELECT ID IN @InsertedIDs)
```

Comment: `hash_id` should be of type `varbinary` since that is the type returned by the `HashBytes` built in function. If it's a `varbinary`, you wont find it in a list of `int`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks for comment. I've edited the answer.